# How distinguish iOS and OS X nodes on Selenium Grid?

Tags: ios, safari, appium, selenium-grid

I have Mac OS X node with Safari and Appium iOS node.
They both have platform:MAC, browser:Safari and version:9.
mobilePlatform capability is not taken into account by the grid
Platform iOS does not exist in the enumeration.
I set on the iOS node platform UNIX as a workaround, but I am looking for an intuitive solution without the need to tell it to all Grid users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the attribute `applicationName` wherein you can mention the actual platform in your node configuration file.

So your node configuration file for the Mac OSX node can look like below

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "applicationName": "OSX"
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 5,
    "port": 5555,
    "host": ip,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "timeout":6000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": ip
  }
}
```

and this can be passed on to the node via the argument `-nodeConfig` when starting it up.

Now in order for the tests to be routed to the proper node, you would need to set the capability as well.

For e.g., if you wanted the safari on OSX you would do as below :

`DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
dc.setCapability("applicationName", "OSX");`

and you would use the `dc` object to instantiate your `RemoteWebDriver` and your tests would run on the OSX node.